# Help with changing how jWYSIWYG editor works

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, htmlpurifier, jwysiwyg

In [jWYSIWYG editor](http://code.google.com/p/jwysiwyg/), pushing enter inserts `<br />`s.

Instead of this, I would prefer that pushing enter would wrap chunks in `<p>` tags.

**WHAT IS OUTPUT**

```
line
<br />
new line
```

**WHAT I WANT**

```
<p>line</p>
<p>new line</p>
```

Quick examination of the config seems I can't do it without hacking it internally.

Do you suggest I hack the plugin, or use PHP to do it? The incoming HTML is parsed with HTML Purifier, so if that could do it, that would be great.

So - where should I do it, in the plugin or PHP?
Any quick implementations of how to do it?

Thanks

Comment: What version are you using? Am not able to replicate this on `0.5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could search replace <br>s with newlines, and then use %AutoFormat.AutoParagraph